# Plotting US Map in R

Tags: r, plot

How to plot certain states alone in US and label them?

currently i have been able to plot the states using this function

```
library(maps)
map("state",c('New York','massachusetts','Pennsylvania'),fill=TRUE,col="dark green",projection="polyconic")
```

But i haven't been able to label them.

Comment: spell things correctly

Comment: @Gughan Perhaps this helps `map.text("state", c('New York','Massachusetts', 'Pennsylvania'),  col='black');
map("state", c('New York','Massachusetts', 'Pennsylvania'),  fill=TRUE, col='dark green', add=TRUE);
 map.text("state", c('New York','Massachusetts', 'Pennsylvania'),  col='black', add=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ggmap and ggplot2 packages to plot the US states in US map.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
usaState<- data.frame(c("new york", "massachusetts", "pennsylvania"))
colnames(usaState) <- "statename"
LatLon <-  c(apply(usaState, 1, geocode))
LatLonDF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, LatLon)
stateLatLonDF <- cbind(usaState, LatLonDF)
myMap <- ggmap(get_map(location = 'united states', zoom = 4, source = 'google', maptype="terrain"))
myMap <- myMap + geom_text(data = stateLatLonDF, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = statename), size = 3, vjust = 0, hjust = -0.1, color = "red")
print(myMap)
```

The zoom, text parameters, etc. can be changed according to your need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it helps.Is it possible that i can zoom only the East coast where my plot is concentrated?

Answer (score 0):

@Gughan In the previous code snippet, I used get_map(location = 'united states') to get the map, which brings the whole map of US. To zoom in to a particular location, the location of get_map() can be obtained by the mean of the latitudes and longitudes. By controlling the zoom parameter in get_map(), and running the following code, I am getting the East coast zoomed.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
usaState<- data.frame(c("new york", "massachusetts", "pennsylvania"))
colnames(usaState) <- "statename"
LatLon <-  c(apply(usaState, 1, geocode))
LatLonDF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, LatLon)
stateLatLonDF <- cbind(usaState, LatLonDF)
map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(stateLatLonDF$lon), lat = mean(stateLatLonDF$lat)), color="color",source="google", maptype="terrain", zoom=7)
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = stateLatLonDF, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = statename, alpha = 0.5, fill = "red"), size = 5, shape = 21) + geom_text(data = stateLatLonDF, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = statename), size = 3, vjust = 0, hjust = -0.1, color = "blue") + scale_colour_discrete(name  = "statename")
```